# How to check if collection is thread safe?

Tags: java, collections

Is there any possibility to check if given collection from java.util.collections is thread safe?

Comment: `thread save` ?? do you mean `thread safe`

Comment: By reading the documentation .. if there are no guarantees provided then it is *not* thread-safe. (Even the thread-safe variants in the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package have caveats.)

Comment: Thanks for a clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps in order

1. Read documentation (if they say so)
2. Check code if available (If code/methods you're using are)
3. Test it using a simple multi threaded program.(Do this any way)

Comment: Show us a "simple" multi-threaded program which can reliably verify the thread-safety of a class.

Comment: whoops, shouldn't use the word simple

Comment: Even with a complex program you can't really do it.